# ¿Cómo selecciono los datos de un array que no estén en otro array?

Tags: php, array

Tengo dos arrays de la siguiente manera. Array1:

```
Array ([id] => 24 [email] => test1@gmail.com) 
Array ([id] => 25 [email] => test2@gmail.com) 
Array ([id] => 27 [email] => test3@hotmail.com) 
Array ([id] => 29 [email] => test4@gmail.com) 
Array ([id] => 32 [email] => test9@gmail.com)
```

Y un segundo array:

```
Array ([id] => 24 [email] => test1@gmail.com) 
Array ([id] => 25 [email] => test2@gmail.com)
Array ([id] => 26 [email] => test31@gmail.com) 
Array ([id] => 29 [email] => test4@gmail.com) 
Array ([id] => 33 [email] => test19@gmail.com)
```

Quiero que me imprima un array con los elementos del array1 que no esten en el array2 ya que me encuentro atascado.

Por lo que el resultado esperado fuera:

```
Array ([id] => 27 [email] => test3@hotmail.com)
Array ([id] => 32 [email] => test9@gmail.com)
```

Comment: Yo veo los mismos datos en ambos arrays...

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Disculpa, editado. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se hace con la función *[array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php)*. Esta función hace exactamente lo que pides: devuelve los valores del primer array que no se encuentran en ninguno de los demás arrays (ya que admite comparación con múltiples arrays). La función devuelve los valores como otro array.

Así que en tu caso simplemente deberías hacer:

```
$arr_1    = array(...);
$arr_2    = array(...);
$valores= array_diff($arr_1, $arr_2);
```

---

**UPDATE**

En tu caso (tal y como puntualizas en tu comentario), al manejar arrays de dos dimensiones, creo que habría que hacerlo a mano. Es posible que haya alguna función o algún algoritmo simple.

```
$arr_1 = array(
    array('id' => 24, 'email' => 'test1@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 25, 'email' => 'test2@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 27, 'email' => 'test3@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 29, 'email' => 'test4@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 32, 'email' => 'test9@gmail.com')
);

$arr_2 = array(
    array('id' => 24, 'email' => 'test1@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 25, 'email' => 'test2@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 26, 'email' => 'test31@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 29, 'email' => 'test4@gmail.com'),
    array('id' => 33, 'email' => 'test19@gmail.com')
);

$resultado = array();
$n = count($arr_1);
$m = count($arr_2);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    $coincidencia = false;
    for($j=0;$j<$m;$j++){
        if($arr_1[$i] == $arr_2[$j]){
            $coincidencia = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$coincidencia){
        $resultado[] = $arr_1[$i];
    }
}

print_r($resultado);
```

Lo que hacemos es comparar los arrays, entrada a entrada, y al igual que ocurre con integers, cadenas, booleanos, etc...PHP también permite comparar si 2 arrays son iguales con el mismo operador de comparación.

Comment: EL problema es que con "array_diff" me devuelve "Array to string conversion in".

Comment: @fsfrs, tenías razón, perdona. No me había dado cuenta de que estabas tratando con arrays multidimensionales. Si no se trata de arrays con un gran número de entradas, la actualización que he puesto te servirá sin problemas.